# Highest possible value of combinations of 5

Tags: python, r, math

According to https://www.heroescounters.com/teampicker a Hero has a synergy value with another hero, Heroes of the Storm have 60+ heroes each one with a synergy value for example:

```
HeroID  Synergy.With.HeroID      Synergy.Points
1               2                       97
1               3                       95
1               4                       94
45              1                       2
45              2                       11
```

A Team in heroes of the storm have 5 heroes, and the full synergy of a team is calculated by the formula:

```
Team_total_synergy = Synergy_Points(Hero1 with Hero2) + 
mean(Synergy_Points(Hero3 + Hero1) + Synergy_Points(Hero3 + Hero2)) + 

mean(Synergy_Points(Hero4 + Hero1) + Synergy_Points(Hero4 + Hero2) + Synergy_Points(Hero4 + Hero3)  

[And so on... till Hero5]
```

Explaining the formula: Each Synergy Value after the synergy of Hero 1 and Hero 2 is calculated by the Mean of that Hero with the rest of the team, When Hero5 is added up i got the synergy of the team summing all the values.

My Answer is, How can I find(With Python or R) the Team with the greatest possible synergy given that formula, and how can I write the code to find it given the possibility there are 64 Heroes(approximately).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to brute force it by counting all `64^5` combinations of heroes and calculating their total synergy score. However this would take a few minutes to an hour on most computers.

The more efficient approach is to first sort the Synergy.Points column highest to lowest. Then the problem becomes finding a 'path' of five heroes such that the highest position in the path is as low as possible on the table (ie associated with the most synergy).

A path is a list of heroes such that you jump from hero to associated hero until you have five unique heroes. In the below table, a path would be 1 -> 2 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7. The positions in the table associated with this path is 1, 4, 5, 2 where the highest point is 5.

This will guarantee that the total synergy is highest.

```
HeroID  Synergy.With.HeroID      Synergy.Points
1               2                       97
6               7                       95
1               4                       94
2               5                       11  
5               6                       2
```

As for the python code, this is a little trickier.... I tried working this out for about 20 minutes but I realize there are a lot of complications. For example, a path might have a cycle which might create an infinite loop if your program isn't careful.

If you want to do this process once to find the most efficient team for this game, I'd try the brute force method. If you want to be able to run this code over and over again, I'd pose this to the Computer Science stackoverflow and get and algorithm to do this in python.

I hope that helps : )

Comment: Thank You so much @Saleh Hindi, As I need to run the code only when the game creates a new hero I decided to do by brute force, I posted this question in CS stack Exchange and got a good answer as well: 
[link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/76580/highest-possible-value-of-combinations-of-5/76583?noredirect=1#comment163158_76583)

Comment: @Cayoda, I just read your question on the CS stackexchange and that's really cool. I've never heard of the maximum clique problem before so I just learned something new.